# styling jsf tag in css file

Tags: css, jsf, xhtml, graphicimage

I have a web project. I have no trouble when styling html tags, div or class. But when I style a JSF tag (graphicImage) it doesn't work.

It doesn't work neither like this :

```
graphicImage{
width:280px;
height:130px;
margin-left:10px;}
```

nor:

```
h:graphicImage{
width:280px;
height:130px;
margin-left:10px;}
```

How can I style with external css? Can you please help me?

Comment: h:graficImage might me in your code. You have to style what it renders. Or add inline style attribute

Comment: Of course I use h:graphicImage tag in xhtml file. And I want to style this tag..

Comment: Yes, but what does it render on your client? Do you have a live preview

Comment: Please take a step back and learn what JSF is and does before trying things... It effectively just renders HTML

Comment: Yes the photo is on the web site with its size. (really big). not the size I wrote in css

Comment: Yes I know but couldn't I style this effective tags?

Comment: is it something like that what you say h|graphicImage{...} it doesn't work too.

Comment: @MrListener: NOOOOOOO. nothing css namespace related. The server-side xhtml is client-side totally different. There it is pure html. Look at the generated html client side and style that.. .

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry. I deleted my comments now. But you would've got my attention sooner if you'd spelled my username correctly! I never got a notification about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do at the tag itself, by using style attribute.

```
<h:graphicImage style="width:280px;
                height:130px;
                margin-left:10px;"/>
```

or might be like this.

```
<h:graphicImage styleClass="testStyle"/>

.testStyle
 {
    width:280px;
    height:130px;
    margin-left:10px;
 }
```

Comment: Sure but that does not explain the error in thinking in the question and hence the reason for the question. Using a (styleClass) is available all over the internet

Answer (score 2):

You DON'T style jsf xhtml tags. You style the client-side html. Take a browser developer tool and inspect the source of what is in the browser. A JSF `h:graphicImage` client-side side is an `<img>` tag. Style that.

```
img {
   width:280px;
   height:130px;
   margin-left:10px;
}
```

But you can of course use the `style` and `styleClass` as well